# JS not autopopulating SharePoint User

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I've included a snippet of code that doesn't seem to be doing what I want it to. In the past I've been able to use this to autopopulate a name based on the users name within SharePoint. There's no obvious errors, everything else in the script runs fine, and it appears this does to, it just doesn't do what's intended.

```
function getWebUserData() {
        context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = context.get_web();
        currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
        currentUser.retrieve();
        context.load(web);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), 
             Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
}

function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
    var userObject = web.get_currentUser();

    $("input[Title='Requester']").val(userObject.get_title());
    $("input[Title='Requester']").attr('disabled','disabled');   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works in my local SharePoint 2013. [referenced thread](http://www.getsharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-2013-pre-populate-people-picker-value-to-current-user/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function GetCurrentUser() {
                var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser";
                var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
                $.ajax({
                    url: requestUri,
                    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    headers: requestHeaders,
                    success: onSuccess,
                    error: onError
                });
            }
            function onSuccess(data, request) {
                var userName = data.d.LoginName;
                //parse the value.
                userName = userName.toString().split("i:0#.w|")[1];
                SetUserFieldValue("Requester", userName);
            }
            function onError(error) {
                //alert(error);
            }
            function SetUserFieldValue(fieldName, userName) {
                var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
                var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id');
                var _PeoplePickerEditer = $("input[title='" + fieldName + "']");
                _PeoplePickerEditer.val(userName);
                var _PeoplePickerOject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId];
                _PeoplePickerOject.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
            }
            GetCurrentUser();
        });
    </script>
```